# SQL Query for Month wise count

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have table as below for package and its monthly count, like..

`Package1` - 1 dollor per search - 50 searches (PER MONTH) included in package and extra search FOR MONTH will be counted separately.

I am passing data in my table like..

User package table has user's package information with its detail.

```
UserpackageId  Userid  PackageId  SearchPerMonth    StartDatePackage    EndDatePackage
1                1         1             50         25/02/2012         25/02/2013  (1 YEAR)
```

**Detail table**

```
Userpackageid      SearchDate      SearchCost      
1                  26/02/2012       1 Dollor
```

Now I want to summarize data like

monthly package search count - as I have search per month 50 for that package.. and if extra count happens over 50 than It will show other count for extra IN MONTHLY WISE..

Comment: Very unclear question, to be honest with you... Try to re-write it completely. 1.What do you have as input? 2.What do you want as output? 3.How do you try to reach you goal?

Comment: I want to summarize above table's data month wise..  For ex. username xyz searched 34 employees for first month from when his package started (guessing yearly package) - so above example data has 50 search available for his package .. so for each month he can search 50 and if over 50 then  I want those count seperately.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Smarty that your question is pretty tough to read so I'll have to make some assumptions on your requirements.

See if this help you.

```
create table UserPackage(ID int identity(1,1), UserID int, PackageID int,
    SearchPerMonth int, StartDate datetime, EndDate datetime)
create table Detail(ID int identity(1,1), UserPackageID int, SearchDate datetime,Cost money)

insert into UserPackage(UserID, PackageID, SearchPerMonth, StartDate, EndDate) 
    values(1,1,3,'2/15/12','2/15/13')

insert into Detail(UserPackageID,SearchDate,Cost) values(1,'2/16/12',1)
insert into Detail(UserPackageID,SearchDate,Cost) values(1,'2/17/12',2)
insert into Detail(UserPackageID,SearchDate,Cost) values(1,'2/18/12',3)
insert into Detail(UserPackageID,SearchDate,Cost) values(1,'2/19/12',4)
insert into Detail(UserPackageID,SearchDate,Cost) values(1,'2/20/12',5)

select 
    UserPackageID,
    CostInLimit=sum(CostInLimit),
    CostAboveLimit=sum(CostAboveLimit)
from
    (
    select
        z.UserPackageID,
        z.DetailID,
        IsInLimit=case when z.RankInMonth > up.SearchPerMonth then 1 else 0 end,
        CostInLimit=case when z.RankInMonth > up.SearchPerMonth then Cost else 0 end,
        CostAboveLimit=case when z.RankInMonth > up.SearchPerMonth then 0 else Cost end,
        z.Cost,
        z.RankInMonth,
        z.SearchDate
    from
        UserPackage up
        inner join
        (
            select
                DetailID=ID,
                UserPackageID,
                Cost,
                RankInMonth=RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY UserPackageID ORDER BY SearchDate),
                SearchDate
            from 
                Detail 
        ) z on z.UserPackageID = up.ID
    ) y 
where
    y.SearchDate between '2/15/12' and '3/15/12'
group by
    UserPackageID][1]
```

Here's the result from the outer select:

[image]

Here's the result from the inner select (table y by itself):
[image]

Comment: Hi, Your query is little different. Cost per search will be in userpackage table. And in your example 3 search available per month but It returns incorrect result.. For extra search after first 3 search it should return isinlimit = 0.  Also if I add some search records for other months in that year then - It should work accordingly for those months as well.  Thanks for your reply.. Can you please give some changes to make it help me.

Comment: Also I want data for whole year with count. Main problem I am getting there when I am partitioning for each month for that year.